# Why would it take 10 minutes to download a 2MB js file on localhost?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, maven, tomcat7

I am developing a Java web application and am using Apache Tomcat 7.0.53 to access with my localhost.  Using Windows 7 and Chrome Version 35.0.1916.86 beta-m.  We have several javascript files that are concatenated together and minified.  We've allowed a maven option to not minify the code while the concatenating happens.  So in one example file I have jquery (minified) followed by some other custom js (not minified).  Throughout my workday I will have several times where Chrome downloads these larger js files in 8192 byte chunks.  The problem is that there is sometimes a pause between each 8K chunk.  I just waited 12 minutes for a 2.3MB js file to be completely loaded.
After load, the evaluate script:
Self Time: 458.000 ms
Start Time: 12.3 min
Script: Metrics.min.js:1
Used JavaScript Heap Size: 16.1 MB (+5.5 MB)

This doesn't seem to happen in Firefox.  Not sure about IE.  Is this a Chrome issue, a Maven build issue, a Tomcat configuration issue?

Comment: Most likely a Tomcat problem... Can you capture this with Wireshark?

Comment: Does the script do anything once it's loaded? Might the time include any code execution?

Comment: I verified this happening in Firefox as well, so it's looking more like a Tomcat problem.  The script does a lot after it is loaded, it isn't doing code execution as I can tell in Chrome Dev tools it is just "Received Data".  I don't know about Wireshark, I will look into that. Thanks!